# enable IST timezone in puppet

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm trying to run below Puppet manifest to set 'IST' timezone.

```
class { 'timezone':
  timezone => 'IST',
}
```

When I run Puppet apply `timezone.pp`, it installs properly. But when I check the system date, It's the same as before. I don't see any change in timezone. Also when I change IST to PST or some other timezone, it works properly. Only IST is not working for me.

I had installed timezone Puppet module and kept it in `/etc/puppet/module` directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: @slm India Standard Time, e.g. `India/Calcutta`.

Comment: @slm : still not able to change after using India/Calcutta.

Comment: Perhaps one of the other ones I've added to my answer. I'm not sure what's located where.

Comment: How about `India/Kolkata`?

Comment: Sorry, make that `Asia/Kolkata`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use the timezone formats that are shown when you run this command:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones | head -4
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
```

Perhaps one of these would work for IST:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones | grep "^Ind"
Indian/Antananarivo
Indian/Chagos
Indian/Christmas
Indian/Cocos
Indian/Comoro
Indian/Kerguelen
Indian/Mahe
Indian/Maldives
Indian/Mauritius
Indian/Mayotte
Indian/Reunion
```

Or try this timezone suggested by [@Mikel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114990/enable-ist-timezone-in-puppet#comment178523_114990), which was left in the comments:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones  | grep -i kol
Asia/Kolkata
```

Looking at this example from Puppet Forge, [saz/timezone](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/saz/timezone):

```
Set timezone to UTC
    class { 'timezone':
        timezone => 'UTC',
    }
Set timezone to Europe/Berlin
    class { 'timezone':
        timezone => 'Europe/Berlin',
    }
```

#### Ruby + tzinfo

Best I can tell the Puppet module is just making use of Ruby's `tzinfo` gem. If you fire up `irb`:

```
$ irb
> require 'tzinfo'
=> true
>
```

If I try and make use of either "IST" or "India/Calcutta" it throws an exception:

```
> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('India/Calcutta')
TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier: no such file to load -- tzinfo/definitions/India/Calcutta
    from /home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/tzinfo-0.3.29/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:125:in `rescue in get'
    from /home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/tzinfo-0.3.29/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:100:in `get'
    from (irb):7
    from /home/saml/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

But if I use one of the other timezone strings I mentioned:

```
> tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('Indian/Comoro')
 => #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Indian/Comoro> 
>
```

Comment: as I already mentioned, other timezones like PST and UTC are working fine for me but not IST.

Comment: I'm not surprised that UTC works, that's shown in all the examples.